# messaging().onNotificationOpenedApp is never triggered, messaging().getInitialNotification() is triggered but remoteMessage is always null

Tags: android, react-native, background, messaging, react-native-firebase

I'm using react-native-firebase v6.4.0. I successfully registered a background handler with `setBackgroundMessageHandler` and everything works fine. Now I'm trying to handle notification tap when the app is in background/quit and I'm using `onNotificationOpenedApp`/`getInitialNotification`. The problem I'm facing is that the first method is never triggered while the second is triggered but `remoteMessage` parameter is always `null`. I've also tried to generate a release build but the result is the same.

index.js

```
// imports

messaging().setBackgroundMessageHandler(async remoteMessage => {
  // storing the message with redux
});

function HeadlessCheck({isHeadless}) {
  return isHeadless ? null : <App />;
}

AppRegistry.registerComponent(appName, () => HeadlessCheck);
```

App.js

```
// other imports
import messaging from '@react-native-firebase/messaging';
import {store, persistor} from './Store';

export default function App() {
  useEffect(() => {
    (async () => await messaging().registerDeviceForRemoteMessages())();

    const unsubscribe = messaging().onMessage(async remoteMessage => {
      store.dispatch(storeNews(remoteMessage));
    });

    messaging().onNotificationOpenedApp(remoteMessage => {
      // The below code gets never executed
      Alert.alert('here');
      console.log(
        'Notification caused app to open from background state:',
        remoteMessage,
      );
    });

    messaging()
      .getInitialNotification()
      .then(remoteMessage => {
        console.log(remoteMessage); // always prints null
        if (remoteMessage) {
          // Never reached
          Alert.alert('here');
          console.log(
            'Notification caused app to open from quit state:',
            remoteMessage,
          );
        }
      });

    return unsubscribe;
  }, []);

  return (
    <>
      <StatusBar barStyle="dark-content" />
      <Provider store={store}>
        <PersistGate loading={null} persistor={persistor}>
          <RootNavigator />
        </PersistGate>
      </Provider>
    </>
  );
}
```

react-native info:

```
System:
    OS: Windows 10 10.0.18363
    CPU: (8) x64 Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-8550U CPU @ 1.80GHz
    Memory: 6.90 GB / 15.73 GB
  Binaries:
    Node: 10.15.3 - C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.EXE
    Yarn: 1.9.4 - C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\npm\yarn.CMD
    npm: 6.14.1 - C:\Program Files\nodejs\npm.CMD
  SDKs:
    Android SDK:
    API Levels: 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28
    Build Tools: 23.0.1, 25.0.0, 26.0.1, 26.0.2, 26.0.3, 27.0.3, 28.0.2, 28.0.3
    System Images: Google APIs Intel x86 Atom, android-27
Intel x86 Atom
  IDEs:
    Android Studio: Version  3.5.0.0 AI-191.8026.42.35.6010548
  npmPackages:
    react: 16.9.0 => 16.9.0
    react-native: 0.61.5 => 0.61.5
```

package.json:

```
{
  ...
  "@react-native-firebase/app": "^6.4.0",
  "@react-native-firebase/messaging": "^6.4.0",
  ...
}
```

I tried to run the code on both a physical Android device and on an Android emulator and I got the same behaviour.

Physical device specs:

```
Model code: SM-G975F 
Android version: 10
```

Emulator specs:

```
Name: Nexus_5X_API_27_x86
Device: Nexus 5X (Google)
Path: C:\Users\user\.android\avd\Nexus_5X_API_27_x86.avd
Based on: Android API 27 Tag/ABI: google_apis/x86
```

I appreciate any help. Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I find what cause my problem. I have in my app a config for native Splash Screen, implementation necessary to use the [react-native-splash-screen](https://github.com/crazycodeboy/react-native-splash-screen) package.

I added a news file called `SplashActivity.java`:

```java
public class SplashActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        try {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            finish();
       }
        catch(Exception e) {
           System.out.println(e.getMessage());
       }
```

I mande the SplashActivity my main Activity , in `AndroidManifest.xml`:

```xml
       <activity
          android:name=".SplashActivity"
          android:theme="@style/SplashTheme"
          android:label="@string/app_name">
          <intent-filter>
              <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
              <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
          </intent-filter>
        </activity>

      <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"
        android:exported="true" />
```

Then changes some logic on my `MainActivity.java`, that  looks like :

```java
import android.os.Bundle;
import org.devio.rn.splashscreen.SplashScreen;
public class MainActivity extends ReactActivity {
 @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        SplashScreen.show(this);
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }
}
```

So the events are not passed correctly, more information about see this comments on this react-native-firebase repo's [issue](https://github.com/invertase/react-native-firebase/issues/1272)

- More explanations problem on [this comment](https://github.com/invertase/react-native-firebase/issues/1272#issuecomment-417484397)

> My solution to this problem is pretty implementation specific, but you never know what might help.
>
> My issue was that I had a splash activity which was the actual launcher activity. To get the callbacks to fire in App.js I had to:
>   Add "singleTop" to the activity tag for SplashActivity.java in AndroidManifest.xml
>   Use "this.getIntent();" within the onCreate method of SplashActivity.java to intercept the intent from the firebase notification open event
>   Use .getExtras() to take the bundle from the intercepted intent and attach it to a new intent forwarded to .MainActivity
>   As soon as .MainActivity had access to the intent all of the callbacks began firing on the correct events.

- Implementation to solve the problem on [this comment](https://github.com/invertase/react-native-firebase/issues/1272#issuecomment-421424104)

So I added this logic on may SplashActivity:

```java
        Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
        if (extras != null) {
            intent.putExtras(extras);
        }
```

Now looks like:

```java
public class SplashActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        try {
  //  Block of code to try
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);

        // Pass along FCM messages/notifications etc.
        Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
        if (extras != null) {
            intent.putExtras(extras);
        }
        startActivity(intent);
        finish();
}
catch(Exception e) {
  //  Block of code to handle errors
  System.out.println(e.getMessage());
}
    }
}
```

Now I can get `getInitialNotification()` return  and `onNotificationOpenedApp()` events.
On Android if the app is in background or quit state is always called getInitialNotification(), this is probably because my logic from Splash Screen. But for me it's OK for now, I would do exactly the same thing on both

Comment: I had the same problem, your solution worked brilliantly. Thank you

Comment: brilliant but too complicated. Any simpler solution?

Comment: @kasra No need for separate activity, you can directly use SplashScreen.show(this) in the MainActivity and you will receive getInitialNotification() for both the events

Comment: I don't use any SplashScreen packages, but I still have this problem. Any other ideas?